# How to solve " cannot access disposed object System.net.HttpWebResponse"?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, console-application, httpwebresponse

I have a console app that makes calls to servers. I realized that I missed putting this into using statment and once I did that I kept getting this error:

> "Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name:
>   'System.Net.HttpWebResponse'."

After google I tried a few attempts, one of being:

```
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
```

in the app.config

I still get the same error and I don't know why,
my code:

```
public static HttpWebResponse CallServer(string url)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    var webResp = (HttpWebResponse)null;
    using (webResp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {

    }

    return webResp;
}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `using (webResp ...)` causes the response to be disposed at the end bracket of the `using` statement. Accessing the response after that will fail.

The easy solution is to delay disposing of the `webResp` until you are really done with it. You can dispose it in the method receiving `webResp`.

I guess you should create a `using` somewhat like this:

```
using (HttpWebResponse x = CallServer(url))
{ }
```

And remove the `using` inside the `CallServer` method.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler translates the `using` statement to something like this:

```
HttpWebResponse webResp;
try
{
    webResp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
finally
{
    webResp.Dispose();
}
```

So if you want to return `webResp` and use this object outside your method, you must not put it inside a `using` statement, because `using` will `Dispose` the object. And you cannot use a disposed object (as the exception message clearly states).

You probably wanted to wrap your call to `CallServer` in a `using` statement:

```
using (HttpWebResponse webResp = CallServer("http://..."))
{
   // do something with your response
}
```